# I cannot get rigid body physics to work properly

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Can anyone have a look at my file and or tell me how I can fix this and achieve what I am trying to achieve here? I am trying to make a rosary that a monk would where animate and I started with basic rigid body experiments to see what I could get working and I could not even move on from my first test on things because as soon as I add a passive rigid body to the clothes just to see what the rosery does, it goes upwards. And it goes down without a passive rigid body object. Here is the drop box link to the file.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/a2rcvuwyc55dnci9d11f7/RuyLopez.Testblend.blend?rlkey=ljzuic9jpm9d6wx020mqv355l&dl=0

Comment: Maybe you should have written that you are a total Blender beginner....https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties/collisions.html -> convex hull as shape for rigid body can only be used for very simple objects like boxes. If you would shrinkwrap your rosary, you would get a "circle like" thing with thickness. That's why it flies off. So you have to use shape "mesh" in your case for both, cloth and rosary.

Comment: the second big problem is, that you didn't apply scale and rotation for both objects. Rigid body simulation will act weird if you don't apply that.

Comment: the third problem is, that a rosary is NOT a rigid body and the simulation will look totally unrealistic if you fix the two problems i told you: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oplsA.gif

Comment: So either you can try it with softbody simulation, or cloth simulation or rigid body, but a lot of rigid bodies (for each segment one) and maybe connect them with a point hinge.

Comment: Okay, that helps thanks! I have not done anything in Blender in like a year or anything in CG for that matter and I have never tried anything like this before. It seemed like a complex ambition, but I will take your advice and see if I can make anything of it. Thanks again!